# Dependency problem with thingsboard-gateway package installer in linux debian 9

Tags: python, linux, iot, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

i've recently been trying to install Thingsboard Gateway on a gateway running linux Debian 9 32bits, but the packages installer says "missing dependency: python3-paho-mqtt", i have python2.7 and python3.5.3 installed so i tried:

`sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt`

then i get the response

> requeriment already satisfied in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.5.0).

I've also tried with `sudo apt-get install -y python3-paho-mqtt`, but the response is "couldn't find the package python3-paho-mqtt".

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.